# Query against sys.tables/sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats slow

Tags: sql-server

In one app I am maintaining there is this query:

```
SELECT '[mydb].[dbo].[' + [name] + ']' AS TableName,
    COALESCE(MAX(sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.last_user_update), 
CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) AS LastUpdate
FROM [mydb].sys.tables AS databaseTables
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
    ON databaseTables.object_id = sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.object_id
        AND sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.index_id IN (0, 1)
GROUP BY '[mydb].[dbo].[' + [name] + ']'
```

The idea seems to be that if the `LastUpdate` time is not greater than last query, then the cached values can be used, otherwise a possibly much more expensive has to be performed and the cache will be replaced by the result.

Now usually this seems to work just fine, but on some clients I noticed a significant lag between actions. SQL Profiler shows me that this query takes like 2 seconds and has thousands of reads, while usually it only takes like 100 reads and 5ms. The problem usually is gone after restarting the server and overall only occurs rarely.

While I do not really like this approach, it would not be easy to change. Therefore I have two questions: Why does it sometimes perform that badly, but only sometimes? Can I even be sure to get the result in real-time or is dm_db_index_usage_stats updated asynchronously?

I am not able to reproduce the issue, at least not reliably. Sometimes it happens in the application, but when I take the same query and execute it in SQL Server Management Studio the query runs as fast as expected. I already checked if this might have something to do with connection settings but they seem identical. I once was able to reproduce it in management studio but was not aware enough to get the execution plan and since then wasn't able to reproduce it in management studio again. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Had this issue on SQL Server 2016 and 2017 so far.

Comment: There could be a zillion reasons this is happening. There is no chance anybody not sitting at a desk on location can answer this.

Comment: Too bad, I hoped that it would be something like a known issue with dm_db_index_usage_stats or something, like "Ah, after a restart the problem is gone, because the table is recreated and you can do X to keep it fast"

Comment: By the way, if you could name a few that would already help, because I really cannot explain the high read-count in the one app and just a few reads in management studio for instance

Comment: It is very likely blocking. Meaning your query will likely be delayed until the locks are released. That is by far the most likely cause. But there could be plenty of others.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue with JTL Wawi, which is using the exact same query. `UPDATE STATISTICS sys.*** WITH FULLSCAN;` on all "sys" tables fixed this issue for us.